# CSS Chat Styling

Tags: html, css

I want to create a little Chat. 
The Chat have to look like this:
[image]
But the Datainformation list it wrong...
The CSS is done, but I don't know how I can fix it...

Can someone help me?

PHP Code:

```
    <div class="messages messages-img">
    <?php while($fetch_ticket_answer    =       $query_ticket_answer->fetch()) { ?>
        <div class="item in">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="../assets/images/users/user2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <div class="heading">
                    <b>Test User</b>
                <span class="date"><?php echo htmlentities($fetch_ticket_answer["Time"]); ?></span>
            </div>
            <?php echo htmlentities($fetch_ticket_answer["Message"]); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } while($row_ticket_answer2    =   $query_ticket_a_answer->fetch()) { ?>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="../assets/images/users/user.jpg">
            </div>                                
            <div class="text">
                <div class="heading">
                    <b>User 2</b>
                    <span class="date"><?php echo htmlentities($row_ticket_answer2["Time"]); ?></span>
                </div>                                    
            <?php echo $row_ticket_answer2["Message"]; ?>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: "the Datainformation list it wrong" what does that mean?

Comment: Can you precise "But the Datainformation list it wrong"?

Comment: @mistermartin & Jeff: I mean this: http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=7ecf3e-1481050161.png

On this pic you can see it better what I mean...
I don't know how I can fix it... Maybe the while loop is wrong?

Comment: If you are having a CSS problem maybe post the CSS?

Comment: @ToExeCute ähm...no. What is "wrong" with the information list? The data, the look, the behaviour,..? What should be different?

Comment: @Jeff: how the data look, how it fill it in this "speech bubbles". When I have more then one answer it fills it wrong. I want to have answer 1 on the left side , answer 2 on the other side ( image ).
My Problem is, how can I set this Data in the right form...

Comment: so the problem is in your data-structure. Then you have to rethink how you retrieve the data (from where ever) to have it sorted in the right way. A SQL Join while sorting by datetime could be involved in that.

Comment: @Jeff: thanks a lot! You're right, I thought too complicated.